# QuickBlox - ResourceBindingNotOfferedException

Tags: quickblox

when I try to download the avator using QBContent.downloadFileTask(), I'm getting this error. See below for the Log cat

```
06-22 23:23:11.149  25578-26385/com.connexe.chatapp D/QBASDK﹕ *********************************************************
    *** RESPONSE *** 5f436d20-362a-4a53-a4b9-c25a0230a807 ***
    STATUS : 200
    HEADERS
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
    Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
    Connection=keep-alive
    Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date=Mon, 22 Jun 2015 17:53:10 GMT
    ETag="155319f260019f916ce5c54c84dfdb75"
    QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2015-06-22 19:52:42 UTC
    QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
    Server=nginx/1.0.15
    Status=200 OK
    Transfer-Encoding=chunked
    X-Rack-Cache=miss
    X-Request-Id=ffdb8389df12e95ad2f3aff9663314d2
    X-Runtime=0.020129
    X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
    BODY
    '{"blob":{"blob_status":"complete","content_type":"image/jpeg","created_at":"2015-05-31T12:11:56Z","id":1178358,"last_read_access_ts":null,"lifetime":0,"name":"user_avator.jpg","public":true,"ref_count":1,"set_completed_at":"2015-05-31T12:12:03Z","size":38484,"uid":"228591978d194d58a461388a504b70dc00","updated_at":"2015-05-31T12:12:03Z"}}'
06-22 23:23:11.189  25578-26385/com.connexe.chatapp D/QBASDK﹕ =========================================================
    === REQUEST ==== 7658b488-e476-4eb4-9c13-a51b6230994e ===
    REQUEST
    GET https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/228591978d194d58a461388a504b70dc00.json
    HEADERS
    QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
    QB-SDK=Android 2.2.5
    QB-Token=e28eceb4de27db4c1ad4aff546febcbc9fe03eff
    PARAMETERS
    INLINE
    GET https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/228591978d194d58a461388a504b70dc00.json
06-22 23:23:12.889  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51a25000 size:6012928 offset:5963776
06-22 23:23:12.969  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:6012928 offset:5963776 fd:66
06-22 23:23:13.889  25578-26398/com.connexe.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): 
06-22 23:23:13.899  25578-26398/com.connexe.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): 
06-22 23:23:16.409  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:6012928 offset:5963776
06-22 23:23:16.519  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:3518464 offset:3444736 fd:68
06-22 23:23:17.369  25578-26398/com.connexe.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): 
06-22 23:23:18.919  25578-26383/com.connexe.chatapp E/Login error1﹕ ResourceBindingNotOfferedException
06-22 23:23:18.939  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp E/Login error﹕ ResourceBindingNotOfferedException
06-22 23:23:18.959  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x554ab000 size:3260416 offset:3076096
06-22 23:23:18.959  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x56365000 size:3444736 offset:3260416
06-22 23:23:18.959  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x56c80000 size:3702784 offset:3518464
06-22 23:23:19.909  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:3518464 offset:3444736
06-22 23:23:19.949  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:3149824 offset:3076096 fd:68
06-22 23:23:20.449  25578-26398/com.connexe.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): zlib
06-22 23:23:23.410  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:3149824 offset:3076096
06-22 23:23:23.459  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:3190784 offset:3076096 fd:68
06-22 23:23:26.919  25578-25578/com.connexe.chatapp D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51a1f000 size:3190784 offset:3076096
```

Comment: Please format you log, don't understand anything now

Comment: oky I have formatted the log

Comment: As I see it's something connected to Chat, not Content request, can you check this and provide more logs or code which causes it?